# powershell Script to save users profile when they log off their session

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a script in PowerShell which would save the users data from this path `c:\Users\[user]\Documents when the user log off.`

I currently have something which could work for a single nominal user however I'd like to have something which work dynamically for every users. Here is my current script:

`Copy-Item -Path C:\Users\username\Documents\ -Destination \\SRVIMP02\save\Username -force -Recurse`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are wanting to use the current user name instead of a static name, you can leverage `$env:username` . This should give you the current user name.

In your case the following example should work:

`Copy-Item -Path C:\users\$($env:USERNAME)\documents\ -Recurse -Destination \SRVIMP02\save\$($env:USERNAME)\ -Force`

Comment: Oh it's exactly what i need, thank a lot !!

Comment: NP, if that solved your issue, please mark it as the answer. Thank you